# Display images from ftp server with php

Tags: php, html

How can i display all images from an ftp server in website using php?
It should also sort automatically so i could just add more images to the ftp server and it would work.

I'm trying to make a gallery type thing

I've already looked through google and found nothing that worked.
I'm still learning php and dont know too much about it.

Any help would be much appreciated.   Thanks!

Comment: It is better you share your code here.

Comment: You could use `scandir` and `array_filter` to scan a directory and filter out only images in a callback.

Answer (score 0):

As already commented, `scandir` does the trick. The below code gets all the images and output them as `<img>` elements.

`index.php`:

```
// Here enter the base url of the images folder 
$base_images_url = "http://example.com/images/";

$dir = dirname (__FILE__) . "/images/";

// Get the files in the folder. Sort in ascending order - this is the default
$images = scandir($dir);

// Or is you need to sort in descending order
//$images = scandir($dir,1);

// Output an img tag for every image.
foreach($images as $image){
    // skip the . and .. that starts the folder listing
    if($image === '.' || $image === '..'){
        continue;
    }
    $image_url = $base_images_url . $image;
    echo '<img src="' . $image_url . '">';
}
```

This works with the following folder setup:

```
-index.php
-images
   -image1.png
   -anotherimage.jpg
```

Comment: What about the password? The ftp server needs a password.

Comment: To upload you need to connect to the server via ftp (file transfer protocol). To serve your images you use http (hypertext transfer protocol). When you have ftp’ed the images you can see them in the browser via http. The above script creates the html to be able to see all the pictures in one folder.